# Proving that a Matrix is Invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a complex $n \times n$ matrix. I wanna show that $ \mathbb I_n +A \bar{A}^t $ has an inverse.

I tried find the actual inverse to no avail; then I looked at eigenvalues, also no luck.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: consider $vM\overline{v}^{T}$ for $v$ a on-zero vector and $M = I + A\overline{A}^{T}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in \Bbb{C}^n$ and $x\ne 0$ then
$$x^*(Id+AA^*)x=\Vert x\Vert ^2+\Vert  A^*x\Vert ^2\geq \Vert  x\Vert ^2>0$$
In particular, $x\ne 0$ implies $(Id+AA^*)x\ne 0$, so the kernel of $(Id+AA^*)$ is reduced to $\{0\}$ and $(Id+AA^*) $ is invertible.$\qquad\square$